# MUI AppBar how to go to the pages

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, appbar

I am new to MUI and React. I copied the code from the example "App Bar with responsive menu" from MUI.com into js file.Then called it with in the  at App.js. A menu appears.
In the example code there are four handler functions are there. The setAnchorEInav, setAnchorEIuser are used.
My need is if I click Product Menu Item it should go to the url "/product". How to do that? Any help will be grateful for me take next step in my learning the MUI and React.

Answer (score 1):

Dave is correct in saying you need to use React Router for navigation. Nothing wrong with their answer, I just wanted to include that React Router v6 has been released and adds a more modern and simplified outlet-based routing mechanic.

https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview

Declare your routes at the top level of your project (App.js)

```
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route path='/' element={<Dashboard />}>
      <Route element={<HomePage />} path='home' />
      <Route element={<UsersPage />} path='users'>
        <Route element={<AllUsers />} index /> // 'website.com/users'
        <Route element={<AddUser />} path='add-user'/> //'website.com/users/add-user'
        <Route element={<ViewUser /> path=':id' /> //'website.com/users/012345'
      </Route>
      <Route element={<AboutPage />} path='about' />
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

Dashboard.js

```
const Dashboard = () => {

return (
  <div>
    <Outlet />
  </div>
}
```

Base dashboard pages

```
const UsersPage = () => {
return (
  <div>
    <Outlet />
  </div>
}

const HomePage = () => {
return (
  <div>
    <Outlet />
  </div>
}

const AboutPage = () => {
return (
  <div>
    <Outlet />
  </div>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My Problem is as follows. I cut and pasted the example code given in "AppBar with Responsive Menu" the AppBar with Menu Items such as Products, Pricing, Blog gets displayed. When I click on the Products menu item the handleCloseNavMenu function is called which sets the useState value as null. That is how the code is written. But my requirement  is the Click on Products menu should load  a page consisting of all the products.. The code from https://mui.com/components/app-bar/#app-bar-with-menu.

Comment: Like Dave said. You need to handle navigation using React Router. React navigation is normally done using this library. React does let you navigate using normal target based routing, but this is inefficient for a single page app like React

Comment: This is right, you need to use a Router.
If you use Gatsby you can just do navigate(page.path);